# jq merge json array elements

Tags: json, jq

I have my data in the following json array:

```
[{ "min": 1, "max": 2},
 { "min": 5, "max": 6}]
```

and I would need to have it in the format:

```
1-2,5-6
```

I have tried the following filter:

```
.[] | [ .min, .max|tostring ] | join("-")
```

and I ended up having:

```
"1-2"
"5-6"
```

I do not know how to get from that to expression to the desired "1-2","5-6".
I am new to jq and would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jq -r 'map([.min, .max|tostring] | join("-")) | join(",")' input.json
1-2,5-6
```

If you have a sufficiently recent version of jq, you can drop the call to `tostring`.

If the min/max elements are always in that order and if there are no other keys, you might like to consider:

```
map([.[]] | join("-")) | join(",")
```

Comment: thanks for help , also to you @hek2mgl :) it works perfect now.

Answer (score 2):

Also [string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709718/jq-merge-json-array-elements/53710139?noredirect=1#comment94275693_53710139) could be used, in combination with `join`:

```
jq -r 'map("\(.min)-\(.max)") | join(",")' file.json
```

Thanks to [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709718/jq-merge-json-array-elements/53710139?noredirect=1#comment94275693_53710139) for the idea.